# Display images with different sizes like a table with css

Tags: html, css

im looking for an approach for this design:

[image: Design]

The idea is to have a list with images and make it only with css. The objective for this is to be responsive.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can position them.

Comment: There's no way to make it responsive with fixed positions

Comment: With media queries and percent width/height it's possible.

Comment: Here is a good plugin to achieve this with jQuery. https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope

Comment: You could probably use CSS Tables.

Comment: As @dowomenfart mentioned, you should use Isotope. I have worked with it before and it's very easy to implement. The docs are very straightforward too.

Comment: I was looking the isotope official page, but i don't see an example like i need. There are ways to fix rows or columns, but didn't see both. Are you sure its possible?

Comment: You should look at the amazing masonry js: http://masonry.desandro.com

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that the masonry was working but if you want to try a CSS only solution this one has worked well for me http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout